# How to get selected value from dropdownlist using chosen.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, onchange, jquery-chosen

I am trying to get two parameters from dropdown list change event. Dropdown list uses chosen.js

First I would like to get a name of the dropdown list
Second I would like to get a value of an item that has been selected

I found this code in documentation:

```
$('.my_select_box').on('change', function(evt, params) {
    do_something(evt, params);
});
```

but when I trigger it, params are undefined. Have been looking everywhere, but cannot find out how to do it. Can you help please?

Comment: can't you mix and match JS with chosen?

Comment: I'm trying to. Until now I got: var test = $(this).prop("selectedIndex"); but this gives me index number, not a value

Comment: Ok, I got the name from this.Attributes list, how about the value though?

Comment: you have it there $(this).val()) @weeger answered with a working solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With jQuery, use `$(this).val()` into your callback function, check the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xCSAW/1/) :

```
<script>
$('.my_select_box').on('change', function(evt, params) {
    // The name of your select
    alert($(this).attr('name'));
    // The value
    alert($(this).val());
});
</script>
```

Then

```
<select name="my_drop_down" class="my_select_box">
    <option value="one">One</option>
    <option value="two">Two</option>
    <option value="three">Three</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Actually you can use `params.selected` too